# How to post text in desired boxes on website - then scrape the result next to it?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Unfortunately I'm stuck with the following problem and I'm kindly asking you for help:

I wanted to create a small Python script to track the prices of an electricity supplier, to to see if it's worth switching there.

The website is as follows: https://tibber.com/de/stromtarif#price-calculator

The problem is, the prices are only shown after the zip code and the annual consumption are entered into their respective boxes.

So far I managed to code the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = f'https://tibber.com/de/stromtarif#price-calculator'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find("div", class_='jsx-3205991333 MonthlyTariff')
print(price)
```

With this I can scrape the right  element with it's class where the prices will eventually show up.
For testing purposes, the current output is the whole element, where the subclasses and their values needed are found.
If I enter my zip code and the annual consumption, the relevant output is found in

```
</h1><div class="jsx-3205991333 detailContainer">
```

which eventually can look like this

```
<h1 class="jsx-3205991333 price f-heading fs-xxxl">81,36&nbsp;€</h1>
```

Since the output is only generated after the input is made, I somehow need to post the values into the box, which are at

```
<input type="tel" id="postalCode" placeholder="Postleitzahl" value="" class="jsx-55b7d3df7d2ec18f input">
```

and

```
<input type="tel" id="consumption" maxlength="8" placeholder="Jahresverbrauch" value="" class="jsx-55b7d3df7d2ec18f input">
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. Can you guys please help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: sounds like you want to post data:  `x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)`

Answer (score 1):

That information is being hydrated in page from an API endpoint, which you need to scrape directly (you can find it in Dev tools - Network tab). Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

postcode = '72535'

url = f'https://tibber.com/de/api/lookup/price-overview?postalCode={postcode}'

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.47'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['energy']['today']['priceComponents'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
type    priceExcludingVat   priceIncludingVat
0   taxes   0.0483  0.0574
1   power   0.1785  0.2125
2   grid    0.0638  0.0759
```

There is more information in the json response, you can slice & dice it accordingly.

See relevant documentation for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also documentation for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh wow, never thought of that. I was trying to post and then scrape the result from the page - and that didn't work as planned (obviously).
Thank you very much!